# This correlation matrix table has 46 rows and 46 columns, how to fit it in a single page?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

````
```{r corr-matrix}
library(xtable)
kable(upper,
  booktabs = T,
  caption = "The correlation matrix") %>%
kable_styling(font_size = 7) %>%
landscape()
```
````

This code is used to produce a correlation matrix (46 rows and 46 columns), how to fit the output in a single page.

[image]

Comment: I guess you could [wrap it in a latex box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63651/9459), but the text might be hard to read

Comment: Thank you, but there is no point if it is unreadable.

Comment: Maybe a large correlation plot will do a better job here?

Comment: Thank you @Hao, you are absolutely right. I prepared a corrgram plot. But I'll be more satisfied if there is a table too.

Comment: @koliak are your collaborators good with HTML documents? I do have a solution there.

Comment: Also, I assume you tried `kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down")`. The text is too small there?

Comment: @Hao I'm not sure what do you mean by "collaborator". I'm doing this work for my PhD thesis. Please share your HTML answer.

Comment: @Yihui, thank you for making this question readable.

Answer (score 1):

In the original post, with font 7, the table only covers about half of the matrix. That means if you want a readable table, you have to think about a way to change page size. I think you can follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document and solve this problem in PDF.

In HTML, things are easier since HTML itself doesn't have the idea of "page" unless you want to print. If you only want the table to be listed there for reference electronically, with a new feature I added to `kableExtra` recently in the dev version, you can do

```
devtools::install_github("haozhu233/kableExtra")

kable(your_super_large_table, "html") %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  scroll_box(width = "100%")
```

That will put this table in a horizontally scrollable box where readers can move around and read. You can also define a height there which will put it in a two-way scrollable box.

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply @Hao, and thanks for sharing this solution. It seems I'm doing something wrong here because for html output I'm getting this error: "Error in do.call(paste("kable", format, sep = "_"), list(x = x, caption = caption, : cold not find function "kable_HTML" Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> %>% -> eval -> eval ->  kable -> do.call

Comment: and pdf solution is looking difficult at my level of latex information.

Comment: @koliak my bad. The "HTML" should have been in lower case. I was writing  without thinking too much. I have made corrections in the answer.